# Storing information in cookies, and cookie manipulation of some other domain

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, cookies, session-cookies

We have a **public facing** website, in which the user can login using an email address. 
After the user logs in, we populate the `cookies` of that domain with a uniquely generated `session id`, and  the user details, like emailAddress, Name etc, based on which other calls are made to the server like getUserProfile etc.

However the problem, is any user can make changes to his hosts file, and write a simple `Servlet` to create the `cookies` of my domain, and can accordingly set any random `session id` and user details in the `cookies`, and then can get automatically logged in.

On the **client** side, how do I maintain that the appropriate `session id` is correct. If I maintain the `session id`s on the backend in some caching framework like `memcache`, then each hit on website every page will hit the server, which is not what i would want.

What is the way to get around this problem and ensure that the fraud user is not able to set my `cookies` after making changes in his hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

> On the client side, how do i maintain that the appropriate session id is correct.

You can't. The browser is controlled by the user. You control the server. You can only perform authentication on the server.

Comment: does that mean that every call to the website's every page should authenticate that the session id is correct?

Comment: @Tuco — Only those where the user's identity matters. Displaying the contents of a shopping basket? Yes. Displaying your T&C? No.